# why my container is not coming in center

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i want to open a div in center of my screen ( horizontally and vertically).

```
var documnetWidth = $(document).width(),
  documentHeight = $(document).height(),
  widgetFormHeight = widgetForm.height(),
  widgetFormWidth = widgetForm.width();

widgetForm.css({
  top: documentHeight / 2 - widgetFormHeight / 2,
  left: documnetWidth / 2 - widgetFormWidth / 2
});
```

my widget is coming horizontally center but vertically it takes some offset.

Answer (score 6):

you can do this

define a size for the DIV and position Fixed, like this:

```
div {
     position: fixed;
     top: 50%; 
     left: 50%; 
     width: 200px; 
     height: 100px; 
     margin: -100px 0 0 -50px;
     z-index: 99;
}
```

Or if you don't want to place it absolutly positioned, you can give it a width, and set it to:

```
div { margin: 0 auto; }
```

Comment: Your solution demands fixed positioning, if you use absolute positioning you should consider scrollTop also, check @nnnnnn answer

Comment: nice but i can't give width and height to my container

Comment: in that case how would you set margins

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
documentHeight = $(window).height(),
```

instead of:

```
documentHeight = $(document).height(),
```

The way you had it you were getting the height of the document which could be more or less than the browser height.

And then to allow for how far the document is currently scrolled:

```
top: documentHeight/2-widgetFormHeight/2 + $(document).scrollTop(),
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vULHL/

Comment: He can try fixed positioning if OK , or use scrollTop as you suggested.

Comment: Answer updated to allow for the current scroll state of the document as per the demo. Or `position : fixed` will do it as sabithpocker suggests (I didn't think of that initially because I'm too used to having support a certain application that has to run in IE6).

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely centered DIV without width or height:

http://jsfiddle.net/dFkXq/1/

And acts like a fixed element.